# Make Mozilla display like Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox, size

Is there a way to modify the code so that Firefox displays Everything like Chrome does? i.e Firefox makes everything look bigger. On my website Chrome shows everything nicely while in Firefox everything seems too big.

Comment: You mean Firefox? And it is impossible to give you an answer without code.

Comment: Sure your Firefox isn't zoomed in? Try pressing `Ctrl + 0`.

Comment: Sorry, Yes I mean Firefox. It is not zoomed in.

Answer (score 0):

Every browser has its own differences, so there is a chance that one browser will display a webpage differently than another. However, if size is your main concern, Mozilla has a webpage all about changing the size of webpages or just the text on webpages [[here]](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/font-size-and-zoom-increase-size-of-web-pages?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Page%20Zoom).

Comment: Ok, I guess it's from the browser. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For achieve this, u need first use some css reset, you can view the most famous css resets here:

http://www.cssreset.com/

A CSS Reset is a short, often compressed (minified) set of CSS rules that resets the styling of all HTML elements to a consistent baseline. In case you didn't know, every browser has its own default 'user agent' stylesheet, that it uses to make unstyled websites appear more legible.

Them, use the pre-fixes in properties that are not full supported:

```
Android: -webkit-
Chrome: -webkit-
Firefox: -moz-
Internet Explorer: -ms-
iOS: -webkit-
Opera: -o-
Safari: -webkit-
```

You can learn more about pre-fixes here:

http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/css-vendor-prefixes.htm

And you can also view if a property is fully supported by all the browsers here :

http://caniuse.com/#